# how to get max values in array list java spring

Tags: java, arrays, spring, multidimensional-array, foreach

i have request :

```
"questionType": "questionType",
    "question": [
        {
            "questionId": "questionIdFirst",
            "answer": [
                {
                    "input": "input1",
                    "answerOption": [
                        {
                            "answerId": "AnswerId1",
                            "score": 7
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "input": "input2",
                    "answerOption": [
                        {
                            "answerId": "AnswerId2",
                            "score": 8
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "questionId": "questionIdSecond",
            "answer": [
                {
                    "input": "input3",
                    "answerOption": [
                        {
                            "answerId": "answerId",
                            "score": 9
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "input": "input4",
                    "answerOption": [
                        {
                            "answerId": "answerId",
                            "score": 10
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and i want to get maxValues score in object answerOption with stream filter or foreach, how can i do this?

**i try to this and cannot resolve :**

```
input.getQuestionnaire().getQuestion().stream()
                    .forEach(quest -> quest.getAnswer().stream()
                            .forEach(answer -> answer.getAnswerOption()
                                    .stream().max(Comparator.comparing(AnswerOption::getScore))));
```

and then, in i want to get maxValues, i select to DB and then i want to replace answerOption for request sample to database

Answer (score 1):

For retrieving the max score `AnswerOption` in your `Questionnaire` try the following (you need `flatMap` to flatten the inner lists and get the max comparator result as output)

```java
final Optional<AnswerOption> max = input.getQuestionnaire().getQuestion().stream().map(Question::getAnswer)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .map(Answer::getAnswerOption).flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .max(Comparator.comparing(AnswerOption::getScore));
```